# Regex for english characters, hyphen and underscore

Tags: c#, regex

I need Regex for english characters, hyphen and underscore

Example

Match :

```
govind-malviya
govind_malviya
govind123
govind
```

Not Match

```
govind malviya
govind.malviya
govind%malviya
腕錶生活
вкусно-же
```

Comment: why down vote? please comment so I can improve next time

Comment: I have found various stack threads and blog but all are not working in my case and I couldn't edit regex because I have no idea about regex. anyway thanks I'll take care of this matter next time.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

try this out:

```
^[A-Za-z\d_-]+$
```

`A-Za-z` would allow alphabets.
`\d` would allow numbers.
`_` would allow underscore.
`-` would allow hyphen.
`^` and `$` represent the start and end of string respectively.

Comment: It will also allow to have the first character - or _. Use ^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d_-]+$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
(?-i)^[a-z0-9_-]+$(?#case sensitive, matches only lower a-z)
```

or

```
(?i)^[a-z0-9_-]+$(?#case insensitive, matches lower and upper letters)
```

**sample code**

```
try {
    Regex regexObj = new Regex("^[a-z0-9_-]+$(?#case sensitive, matches only lower a-z)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
    while (matchResults.Success) {
        for (int i = 1; i < matchResults.Groups.Count; i++) {
            Group groupObj = matchResults.Groups[i];
            if (groupObj.Success) {
                // matched text: groupObj.Value
                // match start: groupObj.Index
                // match length: groupObj.Length
            } 
        }
        matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

**regex anatomy**

```
// (?-i)^[a-z0-9_-]+$(?#case sensitive, matches only lower a-z)
// 
// Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks
// 
// Match the remainder of the regex with the options: case sensitive (-i) «(?-i)»
// Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
// Match a single character present in the list below «[a-z0-9_-]+»
//    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
//    A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
//    A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
//    The character “_” «_»
//    The character “-” «-»
// Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
// Comment: case sensitive, matches only lower a-z «(?#case sensitive, matches only lower a-z)»
```

Answer (score -2):

`[\w-]+` this is what you need.
`\w` is word character. it's the same as `[a-zA-Z1-9_]` which means a character from `a` to `z` or from `A` to `Z` or from `1` to `9` or underscore. So `[\w-]` means a word character or a hyphen.
`+` means one or more times

Comment: is it valid for hyphen (-)?

Comment: This answer is wrong according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter

Comment: returning true for вкусно-же

Comment: what method are you using? find or match? anyway, add a `^` to start and a `$` to end, they mean the starting and ending of the line (`^[\w-]+$`)

Comment: `\w` accepts some Unicode characters too! but the OP has mentioned that he just wants English chars be matched .