# Regex for words connected by hyphen and underscore while keeping punctuation

Tags: php, regex

I have been reading, searching and trialling different ways to write regex such as p{L}, [a-z] and \w but i can't seem to get the results I am after.

## Problem

I have an array made of full sentences with punctuation, which I am parsing through an array using the following pre_match, which works well in keeping words and punctuation.

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+|[.;?!,:])/', $match, $matches)
```

However, I now have words like these:

- Word-another-word
- more_words_like_these

and I would like to be able to retain the integrity of these words as they are (connected) but my current preg_match breaks them down into individual words.

## What I tried

```
preg_match_all('/(p{L}-p{L}+|[.;?!,:])/', $match, $matches)
```

and;

```
preg_match_all('/((?i)^[\p{L}0-9_-]+|[.;?!,:])/', $match, $matches)
```

that I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659287/regex-for-english-characters-hyphen-and-underscore)

but cannot get to achieve this desired outcome:

```
Array ( [0] A, [1] word, [2] like_this, [3] connected, [4] ; ,[5] with-relevant-punctuation)
```

Ideally I would be able to also account for special characters as some of these words could have accents

Comment: Have you tried `[\w.;?!,:]+`?

Comment: It input `A word like_this connected; with-relevant-punctuation` or `A word like_this connected ; with-relevant-punctuation` (note the space before the `;`)?

Comment: ...or even `\S` could do it - `preg_match_all('/(\S+)/', $match, $matches)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just insert the hyphen into the character class. But note that the hyphen needs to appear at the beginning or end of the set of characters. Otherwise it'll be considered a range symbol.

```
(\w+|[-.;?!,:])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Examples

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/yI3tM4/2

**Sample Text**

```
However, I now have words like these:

Word-another-word
more_words_like_these

and I would like to be able to retain the integrity of these words as they are (connected) but my current preg_match breaks them down into individual words.
```

**Sample Matches**

The other words are captured as before, but the words with hyphens are also captured

```
Omitted Match 1-9 for brevity 

MATCH 10
1.  [39-56] `Word-another-word`

MATCH 11
1.  [57-78] `more_words_like_these`

Omitted Match 12+ for brevity
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [-.;?!,:]                any character of: '-', '.', ';', '?',
                             '!', ',', ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thank you for the answer and taking the time to explain it; very useful. it worked